# A Simple Python Regular Expression Problem in Google App Engine

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

I am learning Google App Engine in Python.

Here is my problem:

I want the visitor to visit my website in the following format,

```
hxxp://www.example.com/wiki/A_Example_Title
```

The variable after `/wiki/` only contains alphabets and underscore.

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/wiki/??????', wikipage),
```

What should the ???? part be?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are you asking? Why do you need a regex for this?

Comment: I think (\w+) is a regular expression.bgporter's answer is absolutely what I need. Thank you 4 asking Falmarri.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try one of these:

Your spec said 'alphabets and underscore' -- this one gets that and numbers as well:

```
r'/wiki/(\w+)'
```

...if you really don't want numbers in there, use this:

```
r'/wiki/([A-Za-z_]+)'
```

The characters captured by that regex will be passed as a parmeter to your `wikipage` `get()` handler.

Comment: This is the answer I need! Kiss bgporter~~~